# How to open an Xcode file from terminal after merging with remote file

Tags: swift, xcode, github, terminal

Advance apologies for asking such a newbie question, but I recently accepted a pull request from another developer on Github before doing a merge, and now I'm trying to merge this remote version with the one in my local repository, so that I can test it out using Xcode.

What is the command line that I need to enter to accomplish this? Furthermore, how do I open this file, which is in my development branch, using Terminal (meaning what is the exact command that I need to enter)? I'm already in the development branch, by the way, so that part is already done. Again, sorry for asking a dumb question, but I've never done this, and I'm struggling to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Git is not about files. It's about commits. Typically a commit that you work with will have a name: the name of the branch. So am I to understand that you want to obtain the pull request branch locally, so you can try out the suggested code locally, before accepting the pull request that asks to merge it into some other branch? If so, just pull that branch. Do _not_ merge it locally! And do not "open" any "file". If the code is right, as soon as you pull it, you should be able to run and test your project in Xcode.

Comment: A `git pull` should be fine I think. You can open the file like `open Filename -a "Xcode"`

Comment: The commit expresses the _whole project_. As soon as you pull this branch, your _whole project_ will magically transform itself into what the submitter of the pull request saw as _their_ project, and now you can try it out.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your help. I was able to successfully execute the pull locally and open the updated project. Just curious, is what I'm doing currently considered a best practice in terms of testing a version of the app that another developer has contributed? I know that you can also "clone" that version as well, but again, this is the first time that I'm doing this, so I'm generally unfamiliar with what's considered best practice in this scenario. Thanks again.

Comment: @aheze Thank you also. Feel free to answer the question that I posed to Matt if you have an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to know what is "best practice". If you want to try out the code in a commit (including an unmerged pull request branch tip's commit), the way to do it is to check it out. You can't check it out unless you've fetched it. `git pull` here fetches the branch and checks it out. All of that is totally standard. I strongly suggest you read a book about Git before proceeding much further, as you seem to have little mental concept of what it is.

Answer (score 0):

add to .zshrc or .bashrc file:

```
git() {
    # open xcode after merge
    if [[ $1 == "merge" ]]; then    
    command git "$@";
    xed .    
    fi;

# close xcode before checkout
    if [[ $1 == "checkout" ]]; then
    osascript -e 'quit app "Xcode"'
    command git "$@";
    fi;

    command git "$@";
}
```